# C# - Creating X and Y axis with customizable rectangles

Tags: c#

I'm working on a school project.

The goal is to create X and Y axis with numbers, that part I can handle.

Problem is, I have to create numericUpDowns that will allow me to create rectangles on specific X and Y axis with specific size. The size and position is to be controlled by the numericUpDowns. I could use some help as I do not know any command that could connect the two.

Also if there is a way for the numbers on the axis to repeat itself without me having to write it individualy then I could use that as well.

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKH1r.png)

```
        public void tvary(float x, float y, float polomer, Graphics gr)
        {

        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x, y, polomer, polomer);
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x - 15, y - 15, polomer * 2, polomer * 2);
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x - 30, y - 30, polomer * 3, polomer * 3);

        gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x-30, y-30, polomer * 3, polomer * 3);
        }
```

Right now the X and Y position of the rectangles are written in the code itself. I would like to move the rectangles by using the numericUpDows that are shown on Pic 3.
The thing is that I do not know how to do that.

Unfortunately I cannot post more than 1 picture at the moment.

Comment: some could would help us troubleshoot

Comment: @chris-crush-code

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton

Comment: you want to control x and y by numericUpDown ?

Comment: I want to control the center of the rectangle and ellipse by the numericUpDown.

Comment: I'm guessing this is in Windows Forms, then? If so, then you should probably add the [tag:winforms] tag to help others find this question more easily.

Comment: Another thought: your screenshot only shows two NumericUpDown controls (one for X and one for Y). If you want to control the size of the red rectangle as well, then you should add two more to specify width and height unless something else determines this. For the axis numbers, I would recommend using a loop to avoid the manual enumerating you suggest you're doing now.

Comment: Yes it is. I will make sure to put it there in the future.

Comment: Right now I would like to focus on how to move the rectangles using the NumericUpDown. Then I can focus on changing the size of if and yes the size should be also changed by NumericUpDown. I was trying to use the loop on the numbers but I could not figure out how it works.

Answer (score 1):

`NumericUpDown`have `ValueChanged` ActionEvent. So every time when you change the value in `NumericUpDown` method for that action will be execute. You just need in method for ActionEvent to call your method for drawing rectangle. So you need to send parameters for x and y. First you need to take it from `NumericUpDown`

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value);
    int x = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown2.Value);
    tvary(x, y, polomer, gr);
}
```

code is the same for second `numericUpDown`.

PS: You can put start Value for `numericUpDown` control.

Comment: Could you describe how it works a bit more? Unfortunately I am getting quite a few errors. It says that it does not exist in actual context. Do I have to declare it separately ?

Comment: Double click on one `numericUpDown` and you will get method where you can write your code - private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ }

Comment: oh yeah that's my fault. check update. And you should know how to call method.

Comment: what's polmer, you should declare all variable which you want to use at the start of class. then you can call it wherever you want in the class.

Comment: "polomer" is radius in English. You can see on the picture above what I used it for. I'll try to set it up myself from here, if I'll need some more help then I will let you know tomorrow. Anyways Thanks!